# gnuplot plot labelled data

Tags: csv, gnuplot, label

I am new to gnuplot and am having trouble finding the meaning of some of the commands. I want to plot a csv file where the rows are data points and the three columns represent the data label, x value and y value respectively. I want the second column on the x axis and the third column on the y axis and the first column to be the label attached to that point. Here is the data

```
ACB,  0.0000000,  0.0000000000
ASW,  1.0919705, -0.0864042502
CDX,  0.0000000,  0.0000000000
CEU, -0.4369415, -0.5184317277
CHB, -0.4686879,  0.7764323199
CHD,  0.0000000,  0.0000000000
CHS, -0.4141749,  0.7482543582
CLM, -0.2559306, -0.2535837629
FIN, -0.5004242, -0.2108050200
GBR, -0.4140216, -0.5132990203
GIH,  0.0000000,  0.0000000000
IBS, -0.4928541, -0.5812216372
JPT, -0.4821734,  0.7263450301
KHV,  0.0000000,  0.0000000000
LWK,  1.4515552, -0.0003996165
MKK,  0.0000000,  0.0000000000
MXL, -0.4019733, -0.0484315198
PEL,  0.0000000,  0.0000000000
PUR, -0.2165559, -0.3173440295
TSI, -0.3956957, -0.4549254002   
YRI,  1.5555644, -0.0202297606
```

I have tried things like

```
plot 'infile' using 2:2 with labels, 'infile' using 1:2
```

but it reports "Not enough columns for this style". I don't really know what the numbers around the colons mean, although I see them everywhere in others' code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this with the following command:

```
set datafile sep ','
plot 'test.dat' u 2:3:1 w labels point offset character 0,character 1 tc rgb "blue"
```

Part of your confusion is probably gnuplot's shorthand notation for a lot of things.  For example, in the command above, `u` stands for `using` and `w` stands for `with` and `tc` stands for `textcolor`.  In general, gnuplot allows you to shorten a command to the shortest unique sequence of characters that can be used to identify it.  so `with` can be `w`,`wi`,`wit` and gnuplot will recognize any of them since no other plot specifiers start with `w`.

The numbers after the using specifier are columns in your datafile.  So here, the x position of the label is taken from the 2nd column.  The y position is taken from the 3rd column.  And the label text is taken from the 1st column which is where we get the `using 2:3:1`.  It's actually a lot more powerful than that (the syntax will allow you to add 2 columns together to derive an x or y position for instance), but explaining all of that should probably be left for another question.

Comment: Note that, apparently, "_the `labels` style is available only if gnuplot is built with configuration option `--enable-datastrings`_"; see http://superuser.com/a/67452/39752

Comment: Also note - if you use a dataset with strings, and `using ($1):($2):($3) with labels` fails with "_warning: Skipping data file with no valid points_" without plotting - try `using ($1):($2):stringcolumn(3)` instead (note, the argument of `stringcolumn` is column number, _without_ a dollar sigil).

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using a csv file you should set the separator:

```
set datafile separator ','
```

Also, I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
plot 'infile' using 2:3, 'infile' 2:3:1 with labels offset 1
```