# Gnuplot: Treat numeric values as string lables

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file of the format:

```
172.168.1.1 12
192.168.1.0 1
.......
```

They are IP addresses with corresponding connections to them. I want to draw a histogram of connection to each IP address. However, gnuplot consider the column one to be numeric and thus plots a histogram differently. Is there a way to tell gnuplot to consider the column 1 as string labels instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had this problem myself, but this might work:

```
plot "myfile" using 2:xticlabels(1)
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170696/gnuplot-plot-labelled-data) can also be relevant for you.